# wordpress page, post url on nginx inside docker container automatically redirect to root domain with 301 status

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, wordpress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have successfully setup a wordpress site running on a dockerized nginx. When the wordpress site is up and running, I can go to the home page: `https://my_domain.com` or any links or at after `wp-admin/...` without any problem.

But when I go to `https://my_domain.com/sample-page` or `https://my_domain.com/post-id` it immediately redirects to the root domain `http://my_domain.com`

[wordpress nginx post, page url automatically redirects to root domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJcDW.png)

with exception route `/wp-admin/` when accessed redirects correctly to `https://my_domain.com/wp-admin/login.php` if not logged in and to `https://my_domain.com/wp-admin/` if logged in

Here is my nginx config at /nginx/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://my_domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html/wordpress;

    ssl on;
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/my_domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/my_domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications


    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

          proxy_pass http://wordpress_host:80; 
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          proxy_pass http://wordpress_host:80;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
    }
        
    location = /favicon.ico { 
          log_not_found off; access_log off; 
    }

    location = /robots.txt { 
          log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; 
    }

    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
          expires max;
          log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I also config at wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 

if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') 
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.my_domain.com/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.my_domain.com/');
```

Update:

Here the docker compose file:

```
version: '3';
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80" # nginx listen on 80
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./wordpress/app:/var/www/html/wordpress
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db-example
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./wordpress/app/.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=example
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      #- ./wordpress/db/db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/install_wordpress.sql #if you have db.sql of project input here
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'

  wordpress_host:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    container_name: wordpress_host
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./wordpress/app/.env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=root
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=example
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/app:/var/www/html/wordpress
volumes:
  wordpress-host:
  dbdata
```

:
.env file:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=example
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Configure the correct URL in WordPress.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/955478/how-to-retain-domain-name-in-url-configuring-virtual-host-in-apache-2-with-aws/957005#957005

Comment: do I need to add www https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvBkp.png

Comment: Please add more information about the WordPress container. Is it an official image? If yes, please add all env variables you provided for it. If not, add the web server configuration from that container. You can edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: I updated  questions with docker-compose file

Comment: and envrionment .env file